# Unexpected ComboBox behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Given the following code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();

            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3"});
            comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 103);
            comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
            comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
            comboBox1.Text = "Item 1"; // **line 1**

            ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);

            Name = "Form1";
            Text = "Form1";

            comboBox1.Text = "Nanu"; // **line 2**
        }

        private ComboBox comboBox1;

    }
}
```

I expected my ComboBox to display "Nanu" (DropDownStyle.DropDown), but it shows "Item 1".
Omitting the line `comboBox1.Text = "Item 1";` fixes this.
Putting `comboBox1.Text = "Nanu";` in the OnShown event handler also fixes the "bug".

Why is this?

Comment: what happens if you put comboBox1.Text = "Nanu"; before Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);?

Comment: Moving line 2 above Controls.Add fixes the issue, but is not a real option as the first part of the program is generated by the designer (method "InitializeComponents"), the second part is executed in the constructor of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx)

> Setting the Text property to null or an empty string ("") sets the
>   SelectedIndex to -1. Setting the Text property to a value that is in
>   the Items collection sets the SelectedIndex to the index of that item.
>   Setting the Text property to a value that is not in the collection
>   leaves the SelectedIndex unchanged.

So, when you do:

```
comboBox1.Text = "Item 1";
```

You are automatically selecting the "Item 1" previously added in the list of Items. Add "Nanu" to the collection and it should work :

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3",
    "Nanu"});
```

Comment: Nanu is a String entered by the user and loaded back in the form dynamically from the database. So it is not possible to add it to the Items collection. I understand that with my line 1, SelectedIndex is set to 0, with line it is left unchanged, but I do not see why the control replaces my text with "Item 1".

Comment: @MatthiasWuttke combobox doesn't work like textbox, the Text property in combobox works like SelectedItem, So when you set the Text to some string that doesn't exist in the collection, the last selected item would sill be there - hence "item 1". I don't see why it's not possible for you to add "Nanu" later on? Just add it like this `combobox1.Items.Add("Nanu");`

Comment: You are right, adding "Nanu" as an item helps. But: If I set the Text property in the OnShown event handler, it works without problems, while just setting the Text property in the constructor fails. This seems strange to me - maybe internal initializations happen at a later time?